# Forming a big array out of small ones

Tags: c, arrays

I made the following function:

```
int * getMat(char x){
    int[2][2] returnValue;
    switch(x){
        case "0": returnValue = [0,0;0,0];
                break;
        case "1": returnValue = [1,1;1,0];
                break;
        .... 
        etc
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

In the main function, I have these vectors:

```
 char a[] = "010110"
 int bigArray[100][2];
```

I need to populate bigArray[][] by iterating each char from a[], and adding the returned array from getMat() to bigArray.

In other words, for the char sequence "010110", the bigArray should look like:

```
[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0;
 0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]
```

I'm stuck at this:

```
int bigArray[100][2];
for(int i=0; i<strlen(a); i++){
    int mat[2][2] = getMat(a[i]);

}
```

Can someone help me with some tips? I can't figure out how to proceed.

Comment: `getMat` is neither `C` nor `C++`

Comment: How come? I'm noob at C/C++

Comment: Have you tried compiling your `getMat()` function? Already the function signature should not compile.

Comment: Sorry, I did not compile it, so far I'm writing it down, trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I initialized bigArray[2][100] as that it will be its max size, is there a problem there?

Comment: Are you willing to use C++ or just C?

Comment: `[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0; 0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]` : i think that meant array[2][?].

Comment: @ilent2 just C, I need to implement this on a microcontroler

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is bigArray[2][?] a valid syntax? I asumed declaring it with a size larger than what I will need will work. I haven't done any C in years but I remember doing so back then

Comment: i rewrite sample by C.

Comment: _bigArray[2][?] a valid syntax?_ : Wrote so artificially in order to emphasize the position of `[2]`, but not be omitted in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int (*getMat(char x))[2][2] {
    static int returnValue[][2][2] = {
        {{0,0},{0,0}},
        {{1,1},{1,0}},
        //...
    };
    switch(x){
    case '0':
        return &returnValue[0];
    case '1':
        return &returnValue[1];
    //.... 
    //etc
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main(void){
    char a[] = "010110";
    int bigArray[2][100];
    int (*tmp)[2][2];
    for(int i=0;a[i];++i){
        tmp = getMat(a[i]);
        memcpy(&bigArray[0][i*2], &(*tmp)[0], sizeof((*tmp)[0]));
        memcpy(&bigArray[1][i*2], &(*tmp)[1], sizeof((*tmp)[1]));
    }
    //test print
    for(int i=0;i<12;++i)
        printf("%d ", bigArray[0][i]);//0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<12;++i)
        printf("%d ", bigArray[1][i]);//0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you're a life savior :D

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return arrays in C. Instead, what you could do is indicate to `getMat` where it should write its output.

For example:

```
void make_big(char in, char *out_row1, char *out_row2)
{
    char const *temp = "0000";
    switch(in)
    {
    case 1: temp = "1110";
    // etc.
    }
    out_row1[0] = temp[0]; 
    out_row1[1] = temp[1];
    out_row2[0] = temp[2]; 
    out_row2[1] = temp[3];
}

// in main
char big[2][100+1] = { 0 };    // [rows][cols], and null terminator
for(int i=0; i<strlen(a) && i < 50; i++)
{
    make_big(a[i], &big[0][i*2], &big[1][i*2]);
}
```

If your values for 'temp' are all representable by string literals, then you could return a pointer to them, and have the calling function execute the positioning logic. You can return a pointer to an array element, however the array must still exist after the function returns (i.e. it can't be a nonstatic local variable of the function). But this wouldn't work if you needed to calculate the values at runtime.